# Vectorize a PNG file in Adobe Illustrator CC 2017

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png, cc-2017

I need to open a white PNG shape in Illustrator. I want to convert it into vector and change the color. In CS6 is very simple to do this. Can you help me to do this in CC?

Comment: You can't "convert" a PNG to a vector shape, a PNG is a raster image. You can trace it in AI, but that should be the same in CC as it was in CS6.

Comment: its the same thing as in CS6. It's actually better. It looks a little different, but it's still just **image trace.**

Answer (score 6):

The only way that I can think to do this with a PNG is to image trace your file, then edit the result that you have expanded.

So, with your PNG selected in your file: `Object > Image Trace > Make`

Once it's made, you can then choose from a variety of options until you get the option that looks closest to your original PNG. From there, you want to expand and then tweak whatever needs to be tweaked to get it looking like the original file.

Other than this, I don't believe you can open a PNG and just edit the color in any Adobe programs.